# Use jsPDF to generate the PDF of a map on HTML using a GeoServer service

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, printing, pdf, html

I've been bugging people here for two weeks now to no avail.

I have a project linking maps of a local GeoServer service, what I want is that when I press a button a PDF is downloaded of whatever is on the map. Quite simple, but I haven't been able to get it to work or get any help online.

This is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/dw8kb737/

This is what the HTML displays, and what the PDF should look like.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/6lV8eRU.png]

Looking at examples from all these sources

[Export PDF from OpenLayers map with jsPDF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173470/export-pdf-from-openlayers-map-with-jspdf) [Export PDF from OpenLayers map with jsPDF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173470/export-pdf-from-openlayers-map-with-jspdf/175753) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698741/download-html-div-into-pdf-using-jspdf https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html https://gist.github.com/ka7eh/88761650efd3425080035e8535230d15 https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/basic.html https://github.com/mpetroff/print-maps https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/kL68ey5z/ http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/cm1qyk2L/

Did not yield any results whatsoever with me.

I've been working on this for days, why is it not working, what am I missing?

Obviously the code there doesn't work as it doesn't even have a button as I was trying a lot of different things.

Comment: If GeoServer is  providing all the layers then one way would be to configure GeoServer to provide application/pdf as an output format and then make a single GetMap request for the open layers at the extent, etc.  Otherwise (GeoServer is not providing all layers) this doesn't sound a GeoServer server issue.

Comment: You need to enable CORS on Geoserver side. Your wms images comming out are not CORS enabled so you have a security issue.